# ionic capacitor copy ios --> SubprocessError

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I need to make a little update to my app. Didn't use my Mac for a couple of months. Installation used to work, but this week cann't get any further.

When giving command 'ionic build' or 'ionic capacitor copy update' I get following error message:

```
Error

at new SubprocessError
(/Users/ivomans/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:41:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(/Users/ivomans/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:114:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

ionic --version = 7.1.1
npm --version = 9.5.1

Found lots of SubprocessError on Google, but no solution solved this error for me.

Comment: can you try running those commands with `--verbose` flat at the end? that should provide extra information about what's going on and where it failed

Comment: @JulioCesar: command with --verbose gives exactly same error message.

Answer (score 2):

We investigated this same issue and, for us, it turned out the command `npm i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest`, which is executed by ionic cli automatically, was taking too much RAM and SIGKILL was being sent by the host machine.

Currently, the error message from the SubprocessError is being completely swallowed, so if you don't feel like this is your issue, you'll need to go to `/Users/ivomans/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:114:27` and console log the signal and code to see what's going on. Hopefully we can fix the CLI so it doesn't keep swallowing this error message in the long term, though.

Comment: Good to know you recognize the issue. I just don't know what to do now. Hacking into this index.js file from a node_module is a level too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from ShaneTheKing I am afraid a true solution to this error might take a while. I found this workaround, it might help others:

- do all ionic commands on a Windows machine
- copy the 'ios' folder to the Mac
- only run Xcode on the Mac